# more understanding with fseek() and EOF IN C

Tags: c, fopen, eof, fseek

the fseek and the value 0L in the fseek what this value means also seek_end means from end also help me with the EOF <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is not working

```
void modify()
{
 int ch1;
 FILE *f1;
 char c,*word,*sent,fname[20];
 printf("Enter the filename to be modified: ");
 scanf("%s",fname);
 if(searchpath(fname))
    {
    printf("\n1.Character");
    printf("\n2.Word");
    printf("\n3.Sentence");
    printf("\nEnter U'r choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&ch1);
    if(ch1==1)
       {
       f1=fopen(fname,"a+");//use to search the fiel in path variables
       fseek(f1, 0L, SEEK_END);
       printf("Enter the character and CTRL+Z to exit:\n ");
       while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
          {
          putc(c,f1);
          }
       }
    else if(ch1==2)
       {
       printf("Enter the word: ");
       scanf("%s",word);
       f1=fopen(fname,"a+");
       fseek(f1, 0L, SEEK_END);
       fputs(word,f1);
       }
    else
       {
       printf("Enter the sentence and CTRL+Z to exit: ");
       f1=fopen(fname,"a+");
       fseek(f1, 0L, SEEK_END);
       while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
         {
         putc(c,f1);
         }
       }
    }
 else
 printf("\nFilename does not exist");
 fclose(f1);
 }
```

when i run the code and call the
    printf("Enter the character and CTRL+Z to exit:\n ");
               while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
                  {
                 putc(c,f1);
                  }
and when i click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> i got -> arrow mark and enter i reaches to infinite loop
also using
     fflush(stdin);
it lost the address of file and grab some garbage address,

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues, and I'll save the big one until last.

First, it's possible that your infinite loop results from how you're using `getchar`.

`getchar` returns the value of the character read from stdin. It returns EOF (platform-dependent value, but commonly -1) in the case of an error, or end-of-file. However, end-of-file (possibly depending on your platform) only truly occurs if you have redirected a file to stdin when calling the program - ie if there is a file that can come to an end.

CTRL-Z may on some platforms be interpreted as an end-of-file, as may CTRL-D, but this certainly isn't universal and I'm not sure about either of them.

If CTRL-Z isn't interpreted as end-of-file, it may have two possible results. One is to forcibly interrupt your program, a bit like CTRL-Break in a Windows command-prompt. Another is that CTRL-Z is treated as a keypress the same as any other, probably resulting in character code 26 being returned from `getchar`.

Next, I don't think you need fseek at all since your open mode is "a+", though it doesn't look wrong to me either - but I don't use C enough to be sure any more.

Finally - I also think you have a serious issue in how you use scanf, which is causing serious undefined behaviour. Take the following line...

```
scanf("%s",word);
```

Your variable `word` is defined as follows...

```
char c,*word,*sent,fname[20];
```

OK, it's a pointer-to-char - but that pointer is uninitialised. You need a memory buffer to hold the input text, and you need to initialise the pointer. Normally, it's easier to declare `word` as an array of characters such as...

```
char word [100];
```

This ensures that there is some memory available to hold the resulting string, but doesn't guarantee that memory buffer is big enough. That point is a serious one for real-world programming, but probably not something you should be worrying about at the moment.

What's odd is that you seem to have already solved this problem for `fname`. This suggests that you may be robotically applying peoples suggestions to fix your code without understanding the issues, which is a bit worrying. I'll give you a warning, therefore - you don't seem to be using `sent` at the moment, but if it's intended to be used the same way as `word` and `fname`, it will have the same issue that `word` has.